# Как запустить autorun.inf?

Tags: windows, windows-10

есть autorun.inf на флешке, как сделать чтобы он запускался при вставке в компьютер? что в винде включить для чтения таких файлов?

```
[autorun]
open = setup.py
```

Comment: Поставить xp? xD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46270274/autorun-usb-in-windows-10